# Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

i am getting this error when i try to select an item from the drop-down box "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList".  Can someone please help me i am not sure why i am getting this.  here is my code:

```
private void Bind_GridView()
{
this.BindGroupNameList(DropDownList1);
}

 private void GetGroupNameList(DropDownList DropDownList1)
    {
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select distinct Name" +
                        " from MyTable");

        cmd1.Connection = con2;
        con2.Open();

        DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Name";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        con2.Close();
        DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["MyFilter"].ToString())
                .Selected = true;
    }

   //on item change
    protected void NameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)sender;
        ViewState["MyFilter"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        this.Bind_GridView();
    }
```

and here is my dropdownbox in aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="NameChanged"
                        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" 
                        AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Top 10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the code for the page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            ViewState["MyFilter"] = "ALL";
            this.Bind_GridView();


        }

}
```

here  is the method that calls GetGroupNameList:

```
 private void Bind_GridView()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_filter_Names");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyFilter", ViewState["MyFilter"].ToString());
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        GV_Test.DataSource = dt;
        GV_Test.DataBind();
        GetGroupNameList();

    }
```

Comment: are there any code in page_load if yes then pl. post that too.

Comment: Ratina, i added the code for the page load.  thnx

Comment: well there is no problem add a line in GetGroupNameList(DropDownList DropDownList1) before DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["MyFilter"].ToString())
                .Selected = true; insert this--> DropDownList1.selectedIndex=-1;

Comment: added but still same issue.

Comment: Who told you you can select multiple items in DropDownList? DropDownList is a combo box, in which you can only select one item, for multiple selection you have to use ListBox or such similar control. I am even surprised to see that everyone is suggesting an answer here.

Answer (score 12):

Change this line:

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["MyFilter"].ToString())
              .Selected = true;
```

to this:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = ViewState["MyFilter"].ToString();
```

The problem is that you already have a selected item (probably the first in the list) and you are searching for another an have it selected as well. Keep in mind that having multiple selected items is valid for `ListBox` and `CheckListBox`, but not for a `DropDownList`.

Making one of the `ListItem` selected does not automatically unselect the other items in the `ListItemColletion`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, i have made that changes and i am still getting the same error

Comment: @moe Make sure you don't have two items with same value

Comment: i don't have duplicates and also i am getting distinct names from my table as you can see in my select statement

Comment: Adrian, i also added the code for my dropdown in my initial post.  see above.  thanks

Comment: Thanks you.  Been bugging me for a couple of hours now!!

Comment: I was going to answer this for the bounty, but THIS is the correct answer. I don't understand why it's not working for you. The problem is you can't set values on the properties of the items in the list box after you databind. Think of it this way... after it's bound, the list box OWNS those items, and you need to go through the list box to change the selected item. I can explain what's happening behind the scenes but since there is already a correct answer here, I'm not sure of the value of doing that. You are throwing events that you aren't thinking about, basically.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple really, as Adrian mentioned this error occurs when you have an item in the drop down selected and then **elsewhere in your code** you select another item.

To fix the issue put a brake point on `GetGroupNameList` and if the error is thrown at this line:

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["MyFilter"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Place the following line of code above just above it:

```
DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
```

If that line doesn't throw an error it means the second selection is done after the `GetGroupNameList` method call, in that case place `DropDownList1.ClearSelection();` straight after the call for `GetGroupNameList`

Comment: Deni, thanks man but i tried all what you suggested and still i am getting the duplicates.  I also added the code for the page load in my previous post to see if you can see anything wrong i am doing.  thnx

Comment: Where do you call GetGroupNameList?

Comment: i call that in the Bind_GridView method.  I just updated my initial post and added the Bind_GridView method.  Pls. see above.  thanks

Comment: i am still having the issue can someone please help?

Comment: zip your project and post it on Google drive and share the link with me,I'll have a look

Comment: i have shared now so pls let me know if u got it

Answer (score 2):

```
DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
DropDownList1.FindByValue("parameter").Selected = true;
```

Make sure you are not databinding multiple ddls to the same datasource. Being selected is an attribute of an item, therefore, if different ddls select different items from the same datasource, each of the ddls ends up with multiple items selected which is probably what is happening here..

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
```

Before the line:

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["MyFilter"].ToString())
            .Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to not adding default values of DropDownList from aspx and clear all the items before bind data.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="NameChanged"
                        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and change GetGroupNameList method as below

```
private void GetGroupNameList(DropDownList ddl)
    {
        ddl.Items.Clear();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select distinct Name" +
                        " from MyTable");

        cmd1.Connection = con2;
        con2.Open();

        ddl.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "Name";
        ddl.DataBind();
        con2.Close();

        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Top 10", "10"));
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("ALL", "ALL"));

        ListItem oListItem = ddl.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["MyFilter"].ToString());
        if(oListItem != null){
             ddl.ClearSelection();
             ddl.SelectedValue = oListItem.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this hits the crux of the matter.  Every time the user makes a selection you are rebinding the drop down to the data source, but you have AppendDataBoundItems="true" which prevents the previous values from being wiped out on rebind.  You need to either set AppendDataBoundItems="false" (the default) or clear out the Items collection before each rebind.