# asp.net dropdown list findbytext

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following to select have the dropdown list select an item from the list:

```
    ddlIndustry.Items.FindByText("Trucking").Selected = true;
```

Is there another logic for doing this.

I noticed if I do:

```
   ddlIndustry.Items.FindByText("Trucking").Selected = true;
```

and then down the code do something like:

```
   ddlIndustry.Items.FindByText("Cards").Selected = true;
```

I get an error saying cannot select multiple items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
ddlIndustry.SelectedValue = ddlIndustry.Items.FindByText("Cards").Value;
```

The problem is that making `ListItem` as `Selected` does not clear selection of other ListItems. Keep in mind that `Items` property is a `ListItemColletion`, which is also used in `ListBox` and `CheckListBox`, which allow multiple item selection (while `DropDownList` does not allow that, which is why you got the error).

Using the `SelectedValue` propery of the `DropDownList` takes care of the multi-selection for you, unselecting previously selected items and selecting the new item by value.

You can check for a correlated issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068632/570191

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ClearSelection` to clear previous selection:

```
ddlIndustry.ClearSelection();
if (ddlIndustry.Items.FindByText("Cards") != null)
    ddlIndustry.Items.FindByText("Cards").Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, where the other syntaxes would not. (VB asp.net)

```
                Try
                    MyDropdownList.SelectedValue = ValueVariable 

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
```