# If condition for Combobox

Tags: c#

I want that if user click the purchase button but typed a word that does not belong to the list of the combobox it will give a message Invalid Customer.

I have tried:

```
else if (comboBox1.Text != comboBox1.Items)
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid customer.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

but it won't compile and there's always a red line error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net dropdown list findbytext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304968/asp-net-dropdown-list-findbytext)

Comment: You really should explain "doesn't work". That is most useless explanation ever. But look at what you are comparing here. You are comparing the text of a textbox to a collection of combobox items.

Comment: And I would suggest that since you want to limit the selection of the combobox you don't allow the user to type anything. A simple change in the settings of your combobox will solve this with absolutely zero code whatsoever.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" even mean????  No result???  Won't compile???  Wrong result???  "Doesn't work" won't help us help you.

Comment: The "red line error" also shows *why* that red line is there

Comment: I don't see the need for the sql server tag in this question

Comment: I have data connection connected to my combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `SelectedItem` property is null or not

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
    //the user entered a text that is not found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

else if (!comboBox1.Items.Any(i => i == comboBox1.Text))
```

Comment: It is generally better to add some explanation to your answer to help the OP and future visitors understand why and how your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!Array.Exists(comboBox1.Items, x => x == comboBox1.Text))
{
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid customer.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: It is generally better to add some explanation to your answer to help the OP and future visitors understand why and how your solution works.